# How to use composite entity in spring-data-cassandra?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am setting up `spring-data-cassandra` for the first time and have a class like so:

```
@Table(value = "contact")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    UUID id;

    ...
    Location Location;
    ...

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error when starting up:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySQLTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: com.foo.backend.core.Location:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation
....
```

Coming from a `spring-data-jpa` background simply annotating `Location` with `@Embeddable` has previously been enough. It looks like this doesn't work with `spring-data-cassandra`. **How do I use compound entities with `spring-data-cassandra`?**

Will have to annotate `location` as `@Transient` and do some serialization myself? I tried to annotate my class with `@Persistent` but was getting an error about `PrimaryKey` missing on `Location`. I can't comprehend why a primary key would be necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the non-relational details of Cassandra, you are going to find it doesn't work like JPA.

There are no joins in Cassandra, so embedding another table as as an attribute of a table is not allowed.

Embeddable types are not supported at this time.  If you would like to elaborate on the feature request, please create a Jira for SDC*.

Thanks.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/16